# Bar chart using mutable array

Tags: ios, xcode8

How to insert values from mutable array into bar chart?

```
#import "thirdViewController.h"


@interface thirdViewController ()
{

    PNBarChart * barChart;
}
@end

@implementation thirdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lblpass.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.pass ];
    self.lblfailed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.failed ];

    [self getdata];
}
-(void)getdata
{
    barChart = [[PNBarChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+10, self.view.frame.origin.y+300, SCREEN_WIDTH-50, 200.0)];
    [barChart setXLabels:@[@"pass",@"Failed"]];
    [barChart setYValues:@[@1,  @2, @3, @4, @5]];
    [barChart strokeChart];
    [self.view addSubview:barChart];
}
```

I already tried above code.

Comment: I would suggest using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts it has a wide variety of charts other than just Bar Charts and support is awesome. I have used this in couple of my projects and seems to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The Github documentation for `PNBarChart` shows perfectly well how to use the class.

https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart

```
//For Line Chart
PNLineChart * lineChart = [[PNLineChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 135.0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 200.0)];
[lineChart setXLabels:@[@"SEP 1",@"SEP 2",@"SEP 3",@"SEP 4",@"SEP 5"]];

// Line Chart No.1
NSArray * data01Array = @[@60.1, @160.1, @126.4, @262.2, @186.2];
PNLineChartData *data01 = [PNLineChartData new];
data01.color = PNFreshGreen;
data01.itemCount = lineChart.xLabels.count;
data01.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
    CGFloat yValue = [data01Array[index] floatValue];
    return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
};
// Line Chart No.2
NSArray * data02Array = @[@20.1, @180.1, @26.4, @202.2, @126.2];
PNLineChartData *data02 = [PNLineChartData new];
data02.color = PNTwitterColor;
data02.itemCount = lineChart.xLabels.count;
data02.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
    CGFloat yValue = [data02Array[index] floatValue];
    return [PNLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
};

lineChart.chartData = @[data01, data02];
[lineChart strokeChart];
```